# 3-D Space Vector

Tags: java, coordinate-system

I wrote the following implementation of a Vector in Java. I was wondering what you folks thought of it.

```java
package space;

public class SpaceVector {

    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    private final double z;

    public SpaceVector(double x, double y, double z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public SpaceVector minus(SpaceVector o) {
        return new SpaceVector(x - s.x, y - s.y, z - s.z);
    }

    public double dot(SpaceVector o) {
        return x * o.x + y * o.y + z * o.z;
    }

    public double abs() {
        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
    }

    public SpaceVector cross(SpaceVector o) {
        double i, j, k;
        i = y * o.z - z * o.y;
        j = -(x * o.z - z * o.x);
        k = x * o.y - y * o.x;
        return new SpaceVector(i, j, k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Within a mathematical tradition,

- `minus` is an unary operator, as in

  ```
  public minus() {
      return new SpaceVector(-x, -y, -z);
  }
  ```
- A vector-by-scalar multiplication

  ```
  public scale_by(double scalar)
  ```

  is expected (notice that `minus` is actually `scale_by(-1)`).
- Vector addition

  ```
  public add(SpaceVector other)
  ```

  is expected.
- `abs` is usually called `norm`.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I find something like this really hard to read, because it contains so many one letter variables:

```
    i = y * o.z - z * o.y;
    j = -(x * o.z - z * o.x);
    k = x * o.y - y * o.x;
```

I would prefer it like this:

```
    double i = this.y * vector.z - this.z * vector.y;
    double j = this.z * vector.x - this.x * vector.z;
    double k = this.x * vector.y - this.y * vector.x;
```

You can omit the `this` if you don't like it, but I think that the `vector` really helps. Note also that I changed the second line slightly for more readability, and that I declared the variables when assigning values to them, saving a line and increasing readability.

**Misc**

- `minus(SpaceVector o)` should be `minus(SpaceVector s)`
- generally, this is called `Vector3d` (with the `d` standing for `double`), which is a lot more expressive than `SpaceVector`.